# Получение данных через промежуточную таблицу в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть 3 таблицы в БД

1. Мобильные операторы

   `mobile_operator`

   `id`
   `name -- Название`
2. Выделенные коды операторов

   `national_mobile_code`

   `id`
   `code -- Код`
3. Промежуточная таблица где храняться ключи связей

   `mo_nmc_keys`

   `id`
   `mobile_operator_id`
   `national_mobile_code_id`

С помощью `CRUD` сгенерировал след код

```
<?php

...
class MobileOperator extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
    public function getMoNmcKeys(){
        return $this->hasMany(MoNmcKeys::className(), ['mobile_operator_id' => 'id']);
    }
 ...
}


class NationalMobileCode extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{

...
public function getRegNmcKeys(){
    return $this->hasMany(RegNmcKeys::className(), ['national_mobile_code_id' => 'id']);
}
...
}



class MoNmcKeys extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{

...
public function getMobileOperator(){
    return $this->hasOne(MobileOperator::className(), ['id' => 'mobile_operator_id']);
}

public function getNationalMobileCode(){
    return $this->hasOne(MoNmcKeys::className(), ['id' => 'national_mobile_code_id']);
}

public function getMoNmcKeys(){
    return $this->hasMany(MoNmcKeys::className(), ['national_mobile_code_id' => 'id']);
}
...
}
```

Как мне на странице мобильных операторов в `GridView` вывести данные кодами операторов 
Или по другому говоря как заполучить данные через промежуточную таблицу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше в моделе `MobileOperator` использовать [связь через промежуточную таблицу](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table) и отпадет необходимость в промежуточной модели.

```
public function getNationalMobileCode()
{
    return $this->hasMany(NationalMobileCode::className(), ['id' => 'national_mobile_code_id'])
        ->viaTable('mo_nmc_keys', ['mobile_operator_id' => 'id']);
}
```

А дальше для получения кодов просто нужно будет выполнить

```
$model = ... // Один из способов получения записи
$national_mobile_codes = $model->nationalMobileCode;
```

Comment: а как мне полученные данные использовать в `gridview` на странице `mobile-operator\index.php` т.е. опертору соответствовал его код.

Comment: Или как нибудь можно ли данные загнать в `$dataProvider`

Comment: попробовал в  `gridview` добавить в `columns` строку `'nationalMobileCode.code'` но данные не выходят

Comment: как минимум это связь `Многие-ко-Многим` соответственно в результате будет массив, который просто так не выводится через echo

Comment: нужно что то типа такого 
`[
                'attribute' => 'national_mobile_code',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    $codes = ArrayHelper::column($model->nationalMobileCode, 'code');
                    return implode(', ', $codes);
                }
 ],`

Comment: Выдает ошибку `Call to undefined method yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::column()`

Comment: прошу прощения getColumn

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53790/discussion-between-lyhoshva-and-xfirab).

Comment: Все получилось, а нужно было использовать метод `getColumn` спасибо lyhovsha